# Ajax post request don't pass the data of the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have this view where i have some divs: (I play with ajax making hide/shot, fadein/fadeout to see the information i need each moment.

```
@extends('cms.public.layouts.default')
@section('content')

<div class="col-md-10">
    <h3 style="letter-spacing:40px;text-align:center;color:f15d5e;">PROYECTOS</h3>
</div>

<div id="listall"> <!-- DIV TO LIST ALL THE PROJECTS START HERE -->
        <div class="col-md-2" style="padding:20px;">
          <button type="button" id="buttoncreate" class="btn btn-danger">Crear Proyecto</button>

        </div>
                      <table class="table">
                  <thead style="color:white">
                    <tr>
                      <th>Id</th>
                      <th>Slug</th>
                      <th>Order</th>
                      <th>Public</th>
                      <th>Path header</th>
                      <th>Path home</th>
                      <th>Fecha creación</th>
                      <th>Fecha ultima actualización</th>
                      <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody style="color:white">
                  @foreach ($projects as $key => $project)
                    <tr>
                      <th>{{$project->id}}</th>
                      <td>{{$project->slug}}</td>
                      <td>{{$project->order}}</td>
                      <td>{{$project->public}}</td>
                      <td>{{$project->pathheader}}</td>
                      <td>{{$project->pathhome}}</td>
                      <td>{{ date('M j, Y', strtotime($project->created_at))}}</td>
                      <td>{{ date('M j, Y', strtotime($project->updated_at))}}</td>
                      <td><a href="{{ route('admin.projects.show', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">View</a> <a href="{{ route('admin.project.edit', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>
                  @endforeach
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
  <br><br>
</div>  <!-- DIV TO LIST ALL THE PROJECTS END HERE -->

<div id="form1" style="display:none;" class="col-md-8"> <!-- DIV TO SHOW THE CREATE PROJECT FORM 1 START HERE-->
    <div>
    <h3>Crear nuevo proyecto</h3>
    </div>



    <div id="formcreateproject">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.projects.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm" name="myForm">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
          <div class="form-group">
            <label name="title">Slug:</label>
            <input type="text" id="slug" name="slug" placeholder="ejemplo-de-slug" class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <label name="order">Order:</label>
            <input type="number" id="order" name="order" class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <label name="public">Public:</label>
            <input type="number" id="public" name="public" class="form-control form-control-sm">
             <label name="body">Header</label>
            <input type="file" name="pathheader" id="pathheader"  class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp"><br>
            <label name="body">Home</label>
            <input type="file" name="pathhome" id="pathhome" class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp"><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Crear Proyecto" id="createprojectsubmit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
            <br><br><br>

          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
</div> <!-- DIV TO SHOW THE CREATE PROJECT FORM 1 END HERE-->

<div id="form2" style="display:none;" class="col-md-6">
<div class="col-md-">
    <h3>Crear nuevo proyecto</h3>
    </div>
      <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.projects.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label name="title">Slug:</label>
            <input type="text" id="slug" name="slug" placeholder="ejemplo-de-slug" class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <label name="order">Order:</label>
            <input type="number" id="order" name="order" class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <label name="public">Public:</label>
            <input type="number" id="public" name="public" class="form-control form-control-sm">
             <label name="body">Header</label>
            <input type="file" name="pathheader" id="pathheader"  class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp"><br>
            <label name="body">Home</label>
            <input type="file" name="pathhome" id="pathhome" class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp"><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Crear Proyecto" id="createprojectsubmit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
            <br><br><br>

          </div>
        </form>
</div>

</div>
@stop
```

And have this javascript: (The url is correct, and the controller too, if i do it without ajax it works).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttoncreate").click(function(){
        $("#listall").hide();
        $("#form1").fadeIn(1000);
    });

    $("#createprojectsubmit").click(function(){
        $("#myForm").submit();
    });

    $("#myForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:'/admin/projects/postUpload',
            type:'post',
            data:$('#myForm'),
            success: function(){
                $("#form1").fadeOut(1000);
                $("#form2").fadeIn(1000);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

All is working good, except the form doesn't work. If i check the dev tools of the navigator, myForm: don't have anything. How to pass all the data? included the token?

All help will be appreciated, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to serialize the data you pass via AJAX. Right now, you're just passing in the jQuery object for the form rather than its data.

`...
data:$('#myForm').serialize(),
...`

You can find documentation on this function here: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Hi @Tokiin it give me an error: POST http://web.loc/admin/projects/postUpload 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.js:9175
ajax @ jquery.js:8656
(anonymous) @ cms.js?9ae9:11
dispatch @ jquery.js:4737
elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4549

Comment: Use the network tab to see what the error is; it could be anything from the data being formatted correctly to the server not being reachable.

Comment: I check it and don't pass any data. Is an internal 500 server error, no more info :l

Comment: Check and make sure your selectors are correct, I do not see a `"myForm"` in your provided code.

Comment: check form method id mate, i thinks it's correct. Isn't?

Comment: i think i know what's the problem, the problem is miss the token, know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you are passing entire form as object, try below instead. Note `data`

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:'/admin/projects/postUpload',
        type:'post',
        data:$('#myForm').serializeArray(),
        success: function(){
            $("#form1").fadeOut(1000);
            $("#form2").fadeIn(1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi @serdar.sanri people answer this too and it doesn't work

Comment: ah!, I think I know why. try this. instead of `$("#myForm").submit(function(e){` , try `$("#myForm").on('submit',function(e){ e.preventDefault();`

Comment: also I noticed your form is an upload form. so I think you should add `processData: false, contentType: false,` as well

Comment: well, we are trying to help to solve your problem brother, no need frustration. hope someone will point out the right solution then. peace!

Comment: This not solve my problem, sorry if you think i was agressive but it wasn't my intention. I just put it cause you answer first the same, and the other time i think u don't read good the code. Thanks anyway and peace! @serdar.sanri

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150415/discussion-between-lluis-puig-ferrer-and-serdar-sanri).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$.ajax({
            url:'/admin/projects/postUpload',
            type:'post',
            data:$('#myForm').serializeArray(),
            success: function(){
                $("#form1").fadeOut(1000);
                $("#form2").fadeIn(1000);
            }
        });
```

.serializeArray() converts your jQuery object into a Array of key/value pairs that can be sent in a POST

Comment: Hi @ggradnig it give me an error: POST web.loc/admin/projects/postUpload 500 (Internal Server Error) send @ jquery.js:9175 ajax @ jquery.js:8656 (anonymous) @ cms.js?9ae9:11 dispatch @ jquery.js:4737 elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4549